# Does Poco::Data::Session get returned to Poco::Data::SessionPool automatically when session's object gets destroyed?

Tags: c++, database, poco

I'm using Poco::Data::SessionPool class to manage database connections. I need to take a session object from the pool to perform a query. The question is, does this session get back to pool automatically when its object gets destroyed, or do I need to do it explicitly? Documentation is quite vague about it. There is a `Poco::Data::SessionPool::putBack(PooledSessionHolderPtr pHolder)` method, but it's not clear how to tie pHolder object to a Session object.

```
#include <Poco/Data/SessionPool.h>

using namespace Poco::Data;

SessionPool my_pool("PostgreSQL", connectionString, NUM_OF_POOL_CONNECTIONS);

Session GetSession()
{
   return my_pool.get();
}
int main()
{
   Session sess = GetSession();
   Statement sql_query(session);
   sql_query << query;
   sql_query.execute();
   // ...
   // Will session pointed by "sess" get back to session pool automatically?
   return 0;
}
```

Does Session object, born from SessionPool::get(), hold some kind of reference or a pointer to a session inside of a pool? It's not clear.

Comment: Looks like Yes, session gets automatically returned to SessionPool when Session object is destroyed. Or you can do it explicitly with Session::close() method.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, session is returned to the pool automatically